# Unzip by using the "CompressedFolder" COM object

Tags: c++, winapi, unzip, istream

I unpack a zip archive using Win API. This API is based on COM interfaces; the COM model is accessible through the `CompressFolder` COM object.

I encountered the following problem. When I unpack a small file (3.5 MB) it takes a long time. I figured out that `IStream::Read()` causes this problem. It works slowly.  I use a small buffer (1KB) to read this file in many iterations; if I use a buffer that nearly equals the file size, then it works much faster.

How can I get it to unpack fast even if the buffer size is much smaller than file size? Is it possible? I think it is important because the files may be big, say 1 GB.

Here is a fragment of the code that reads a file:

```
...
CComPtr<IEnumSTATSTG> pEnum = NULL; 
pStorage->EnumElements(0, NULL, 0, &pEnum);
STATSTG stasStg; 

while (S_OK == pFolderEnum->Next(1, &stasStg, NULL)) {
  if (stasStg.type == STGTY_STREAM) {
    CComPtr<IStream> pStream = NULL; 
    pStorage->OpenStream(stasStg.pwcsName, NULL, STGM_READ, NULL, &pStream);

    ...
    while (hr == S_OK) {    
        // reading    
        pStream->Read(btBuffer, 1024, &ulByresRead); // it works slowly
    }    
  }    
}
```

A side question I have: 
Is there method to detect a packed file size through `IStream` without reading the file?

Comment: What is the value of stasStg.cbSize? Is it the compressed or uncompressed size?

Comment: Thanks, this is the uncompressed size. However the problem remains still.

Comment: Even if a i set a buffer size to the uncompressed file size i get a little delay still (about 2 seconds). The Window Explorer unpacks without any delay. Whats wrang? Morever if a file has a big size i cannot use a buffer size that equals to a file size.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve fast read with small buffers. Indeed, the more I/O operation you do, the more time it takes.

Try to limit the number of I/O operation by taking a relatively big buffer size. Then of course you must limit it in accordance with the memory you want to allocate to your program.

Aside, you may get delay because program loads libraries. This doesn't happen for Winzip if associated dll already is loaded.